# Generate random amounts of a specific letter in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I generate a letter random amount of times, both each for uppercase and lowercase versions of the letter?

For example, I want to have 0 to 10 amounts of uppercase version of the letter and same for the lowercase version.

Comment: Do you mean you want the letter in a string? So like `aaaaa`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*` to generate copies of the letter. Here's an example.

```
import random

lowercasenum = random.randint(0, 50)  # random number < 50
uppercasenum = random.randint(0, 50)  # random number < 50

letterslower = 'a' * lowercasenum
lettersupper = 'B' * uppercasenum

print(letterslower, lettersupper) #aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa BBB
```